# Typescript: Infer type of object key

Tags: typescript, types

Currently, the indexed access type returns a union of all of the types in the object.
How do I restrict the indexed type to the type of the key?

```
interface User {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    age: number,
    token: string | null,
}

interface Updates<Schema> {
    set: Partial<Record<keyof Schema, Schema[keyof Schema]>;
}

const test: Updates<User> = {
    set: {
        name: 1 // This should not work
    }
}
```

Comment: In the `Updates` interface, the type of `set` can just be `Schema`. Is that what you were after or is there some additional criteria missing from the question?

Comment: @jsejcksn `set` is supposed to be a Partial Record of the keys of Schema. I omitted it for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74845081/typescript-infer-type-of-object-key/74845102#comment132086930_74845081) Thanks for the clarification. I've provided an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74845102/438273).

Comment: @jsejcksn Hi, I have edited the sample to better reflect the problem. Could you take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the type utility [`Partial<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) on your existing type directly to make all of its properties optional:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=13&ssc=37&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChnLAAmAXMumFKAOYDc+yIcAthGRVSHQ2APYDWEEO0o1kAH0YBXADYz6AX1y5QkWIhSoADkTiR0AHgAqAPhwNMYMgAU4UMMDgzjJxcoS8QFZPqtodehCGGNBmALzmBJZkeAQETKxkAPQAVOQOcowQEEToyHDIAG5OUigpSQA0DElJAHoA-AwKVQr0QA)

```ts
interface User {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  token: string | null;
}

interface Updates<T> {
  set: Partial<T>;
}

const test: Updates<User> = {
  set: {
    name: /* still needs a value */,
  //^? (property) name?: string
  },
};
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, this is not what I was asking. I already have them as partial. I just want the values to have the same type as defined in the Schema

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74845081/typescript-infer-type-of-object-key/74845102#comment132086960_74845102) @Arda Sure — that's exactly what `Partial` does. You just need to use it with your existing type.

Comment: Perhaps its easier to see the problem on [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4FgBQyRywAJgFzLphSgDmANAcciHALYSXW0iPPEwAewDWEENxr1kAH1YBXADaKm+AL4ECoSLEQpUAB1JxI6ADwBlBAAsI7OAD4cAopjCUACnChhgcRWYAShAIQlCkZmIAnkIwyFa29gzxNnZwANrRsSmJcAC6DgDcBBr4BKEg1Mim7mhGJhDmGNBOALzOhMRulHidLERsnJQA9MNUUnyyCsrIABQAksgA7nDgJGDVQsgARig80kIgilEAlC7IpWpAA) If you hover over `name` where the comment is, it shows that the type of name as string | null | undefined

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74845081/typescript-infer-type-of-object-key/74845102#comment132086993_74845102) @Arda I updated the answer: it's still the same whether you use generics or not.

Comment: Wow, didn't think it would be that simple. Thanks a lot! Also I have re-edited the question which should make the problem very obvious to anyone else.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply reuse your User interface

```
interface User {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    token: string | null,
}

interface Updates<Schema> {
    set: Partial<Schema>;
}

const test: Updates<User> = {
    set: {
        name: null // Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'
    }
}
```